# Objective C: How to add toolbar in NIB when Navigation controller was implemented using code

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, uitoolbar

I have implemented my navigation controller and UITable View without using a NIB so far. Is it possible to add a toolbar into my UITable View (in navigation controller) using the NIB at this point of time?

[image: Adding toolbar in NIB]

I tried to drag a toolbar to the View Window in the NIB and also hooked it up with an IBOutlet, however, nothing is displayed when I compile and run the code.

Any advice on this is greatly appreciated.

Zhen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is your tableview covers toolbar if you set its size improperly. You can also try bring your toolbar to front by

`[self.view bringSubviewToFront:toolBar]`

Hope this help :)